# Are .pfx files required in the application directory after deployment

Tags: c#, .net, security

If you use a Visual Studio post build event to digitally signed your assemblies with a .pfx file,  should the .pfx file be deployed with the app? In other words is the .pfx required for the app to run correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A pfx is your PRIVATE key and should not be deployed with your app. 
If others had your pfx, they could sign assemblies with it and pretend they are you.
The signing process is used to confirm that you are the publisher of the assemblies.